# how can I set a loading state to a stream in RxDart without creating a custom object

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

My use case is when fetching a list or refreshing a list. I want a spinner to show indicating that the API is being fetched and I do not want to create a custom object(state) with an isLoading/fetching field that toggles between the spinner and actual data.

Stream has the following by default:

`BehaviouralSubject.sink.addError("error")` to enable the `StreamBuilder` identify and error with snapshot.hasError

And also when the `BehaviouralSubject` is null, I can check it out in the stream builder with `snapshot.hasData`

do they have one like `BehaviouralSubject.sink.addLoading` that indicates that the stream is fetching data.

Comment: You may try RefreshIndicator Widget. if you are stuck with it, please let me know.

Or You may use the API request indicator to identify the fetching state.

Comment: @MuhamadJalal not the question I am asking tho

Comment: @Thanoss have you found the answer?

Answer (score -2):

You could show your app is getting data by having something like this in your `initState`:

```
late bool _isLoading;

@override
void initState() {
  _isLoading = true;

  _getAPIData().then((value) {
    _isLoading = false;
  });

  super.initState();
}
```

And then you use `_isLoading` to show the Spinner, or something else if `_isLoading` is false:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container();
}
```

When you want to refresh data, you could do the same done in `initState`, setting `_isLoading = true`, load the data and then set it to false.